# wordpress : how to use a custom HTML file to create a new post?

Tags: wordpress

I have generated pages using a custom template by creating a php file in

```
 /wp-content/themes
```

something like :

```
<?php
 *
 * Template Name: Contact Page
 */
 ?>
 <html ..... </html>
```

and then adding a new page on the dashboard selecting this new template

The problem is i cannot associate tags and categories to each pages.
i would need apparently instead to create posts.
How could i then create posts from a custom html file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom post types and create a single-{posttype}.php

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks !  do u know if it's possible to use a normal post that call a single-{posttype}.php instead of single.php ?

Comment: That's really simple actually: follow this tutorial: http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/tutorial-multiple-singlephp-templates-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

Custom post types are exactly what you need. Essentially, they're custom content containers and an extensible version of default **posts**. They can be associated with tags and categories just like normal posts can.

You can find implementation instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). :)