# How showing the pages inside a specific category (without coding a new template)?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I've a Wordpress site where I'm using "posts" for news and "pages" for some static information pages (about, contact, ...). Now I need to add a bunch of pages: one for each product that I sell. Also I need to add them in different categories (i.e. T-shirt, Pants, Shoes, ...).

The problem: In the frontend I need to navigate to a page that lists all the products inside a specific category. **And I don't want to create a page myself using code/html/php because I bought a theme and I want to use its templates** (otherwise I need to re-create all the layout, styles, etc...).

I tried to [add categories to "pages"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323582/wordpress-how-to-add-categories-and-tags-on-pages), insert products in a category and navigate to http://localhost/mysite/category/t-shirts/ but it doesn't show any pages.
I could consider to use custom post type but, remember, I'm here for have the most simple and fast solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

This basically creates a clone of the "post" functionality of wordpress, and it has categories as well.

The theme will use the same template for normal posts and categories:

```
add_action('init', 'mytheme_init');
function mytheme_init(){
    register_post_type('product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Products',
                'singular_name' => 'Product',
                'menu_name' => 'Product'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'thumbnail'),
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'product'
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy("product-category", array('product'), array(
            "hierarchical" => true,
            "label" => "Product Categories",
            "singular_label" => "Product Category",
            "rewrite" => true
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type("product-category", 'product');
}
```

Comment: I've added a sample code, more info available here http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: The problem here is that the theme treats the posts with a layout that shows date and author that doesn't match to the pages (a product page have not date and author). Another (better) solution could be this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47083/32209 but also here the theme use the layout for posts. Other possible solutions?

Comment: If your theme hasn't an option to disable that information, you can't do nothing without touching the theme files. You can however use child themes to edit the files without loosing them when updating http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: if you go this way, using post types, you need only to copy the `page.php` or `single.php` and rename it to `post-product.php`